# Hibernate is returning an exception when I try to use remove()

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this method to delete an entity from my DB:

```
T entity;

em = HibernateManager.getEntityManager();

em.getTransaction().begin();
entity = em.find(entityClass, entityId);
em.remove(entity);
em.getTransaction().commit();

em.close();
return true;
```

When i call it, hibernate returns this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What statement is throwing the error?

Comment: `em.remove(entity);`

Comment: Are you trying to remove `entity or entidade`? In your code, entity is not managed but entidade is managed by hibernate. I guess em.remove(entidade) should work fine

Comment: I don't get it. Where are you seeing `entidade`? `entidade` is just a translation for `entity`;

Comment: Looks like that is a typo in your original question. It was edited just now

Comment: Yeah, i just translated it to English. Any ideas?